# Uniform Electric field cannot propagate a wave of finite wavelength?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields

While going through the proof of the transverse nature of electromagnetic waves using gauss' law for electricity, I encountered a statement that I couldn't comprehend.

They used an argument that since the wave has a finite wavelength, it could not be propagated by a UNIFORM electric field. But why?

Comment: Could you add the full quote from the reference and include title & author?

Answer (score 0):

A uniform field will have no change in its magnitude or direction.

Since there is no change in magnitude, the wave will essentially be a straight line on the graph. This the wavelength will be infinite.